# Avoid components encapsulation or alter attributes of encapsulator

Tags: angular

I'm building an app with dynamically added components.
For instance I have a block component with a template:

```
  <div id="{{element.id}}" class="row"  [hidden]="hide">
       <h2>{{element.title}}</h2>
       <div class="{{element['col-size']}}">    
          <ng-template #BlockComponentContainer></ng-template>
       </div>
  </div>
```

In my component if I don't set "selector" property my block is encapsulated by "ng-component" which I don't want cause it breaks my CSS framework.

```
   <app-page-form-part>
   <ng-component>
       <div id="{{element.id}}" class="row"  [hidden]="hide">
          <h2>{{element.title}}</h2>
          <div class="{{element['col-size']}}">    
          <ng-template #BlockComponentContainer></ng-template>
          </div>
       </div>
   </ng-component>
```

I would like to either avoid encapsulation (solution A) or being able to manipulate dynamically attribute/directive on the encapsulator (solution B)

**Solution A :**

```
    <app-page-form-part>
       <div id="{{element.id}}" class="row"  [hidden]="hide">
          <h2>{{element.title}}</h2>
          <div class="{{element['col-size']}}">    
          <ng-template #BlockComponentContainer></ng-template>
          </div>
       </div>
     </app-page-form-part>
```

**Solution B :**

```
<app-page-form-part>
     <block id="{{element.id}}" class="row"  [hidden]="hide">
          <h2>{{element.title}}</h2>
          <div class="{{element['col-size']}}">    
              <ng-template #BlockComponentContainer></ng-template>
          </div>
      
      </block>
</app-page-form-part>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I used the hostbindings and went for solution B :

```
 @HostBinding('attr.id') host_id;
 @HostBinding('class') host_classes = 'Block';
```

And I can set my host_classes when my element is ready, the only downside is that it doesn't seem possible to use an ngif on the host or to use a deletable attribute.